# Cambiar a PDO la consulta

Tags: php, json, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera un archivo JSON, funciona bien, pero debo cambiarlo para envíar los datos entre el controlador y el modelo.

```
include "conex.php";

$sql= "select * from timetables";
$query = $con->query($sql);

// Fetch tha data from the database 
$timetables = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $timetable = new stdClass();
    $timetable->name = $row{'name'};
    $timetable->image = $row{'image'};
    $timetable->date = date('j', strtotime($row{'date'})); // date : type DATE. For example: 2016-09-07
    $timetable->month = date('n', strtotime($row{'date'}));
    $timetable->year = date('Y', strtotime($row{'date'}));
    $timetable->start_time = $row{'start_time'} ? date('H:i', strtotime($row{'start_time'})) : ''; // start_time : Must be 24 hour format. For example: 18:00
    $timetable->end_time = $row{'end_time'} ? date('H:i', strtotime($row{'end_time'})) : ''; // end_time : Must be 24 hour format. For example: 20:30
    $timetable->color = $row{'color'};
    $timetable->description = utf8_encode(nl2br($row{'description'}));

    array_push($timetables, $timetable);
}

echo json_encode($timetables);
```

Yo hice lo siguiente pero con eso no puedo dividir el campo date como sucede en el código anterior.

```
class IdController{
    public function idController(){
        $id_URL = $_GET["id"];
        $respuesta = IdModels::idModel($id_URL, "timetables");    
        echo json_encode($respuesta);               
    }
}
```

Necesito en el controller poder dividir el date como esto:

```
$timetable->date = date('j', strtotime($row{'date'})); 
$timetable->month = date('n', strtotime($row{'date'})); 
$timetable->year = date('Y', strtotime($row{'date'}));
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Este es el Model:

```
class IdModels{
    public function idModel($id, $tabla){
        $stmt = Connex::conect()->prepare("SELECT name, image, date, start_time, end_time, color, description FROM $tabla WHERE court = $id");
        $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $stmt -> close();
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es confusa y el error está en dicha confusión. Primeramente si como parece tienes un modelo y un controlador... imagino que estás aplicando un patrón MVC (Modelo-Vista-Controlador). El controlador le pide los datos al modelo, el cual los devuelve en forma de array, en JSON o en lo que sea. Ni el controlador ni el modelo muestran nada, esa es la función de la Vista. Cuando piensas tu código así **cualquier** cosa que recibas en la Vista podrás formatearla como quieras. Creo que el error está en la forma de organizar tu código, o porque simplemente no usas la Vista.

Comment: Sí, de hecho es un patrón MVC, lo que deseo es formatearlo debajo de la línea $respuesta del controller, pero no puedo hacerlo con while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { y lo que contínua porque la sintaxis no lo permite, creo que debe cambiarse, o la sintaxis del modelo para utilizar esas mismas líneas... Darle formato en la vista no es posible porque esa salida JSON la lee un AJAX para ser mostrado en la vista.

Comment: En realidad, aquí: `echo json_encode($respuesta);` tu controller está funcionando como una vista, por lo tanto tu diseño MVC no es correcto. La vista puede ser un archivo PHP como todos los demás que devuelva al controlador los datos para que éste se los pase a la página que los pidió. Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo así, suponiendo que tu `$respuesta` es un array, puedes leerlo como cualquier otro array, sea a través de un bucle for,  sea accediendo directamente a los valores por su nombre de clave: `echo $respuesta["name"];` etc. La fecha también la puedes formatear como quieras.

Comment: Okey... Haré return $respuesta y en la vista haré el resto. Intentaré con un foreach  hacer el formato.  Claro, el debe ser es que el controlador retorne algo y no lo imprima... Gracias!

Comment: Hola, lo hice pero tengo otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66603/impresi%c3%b3n-doble-de-los-resultados

Comment: Te dejé un comentario en la otra pregunta, revisa el enlace que hay allí. En cuanto a esta pregunta si la respuesta que existe refleja la solución del problema sería conveniente que la marques como solucionada para que no queden preguntas abiertas.