# Impresión doble de los resultados

Tags: php, json

Obtengo los resultados de una consulta en un controlador y luego formateo los datos para exportarlos a JSON, funciona bien perome muestra doble los resultados, alguna sugerencia?

lo hice pero ahora me mustra doble el resultado, alguna suguerencia?

```
$timetables = array();
    foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item){

        $timetable['name'] = $item['name'];
        $timetable['image'] = $item['image'];
        $timetable['date'] = date('j', strtotime($item['date'])); // date : type DATE. For example: 2016-09-07
        $timetable['month'] = date('n', strtotime($item['date']));
        $timetable['year'] = date('Y', strtotime($item['date']));
        $timetable['start_time'] = $item['start_time'] ? date('H:i', strtotime($item['start_time'])) : ''; // start_time : Must be 24 hour format. For example: 18:00
        $timetable['end_time'] = $item['end_time'] ? date('H:i', strtotime($item['end_time'])) : ''; // end_time : Must be 24 hour format. For example: 20:30
        $timetable['color'] = $item['color'];
        $timetable['description'] = utf8_encode(nl2br($item['description']));

        array_push($timetables, $timetable);
    }

    echo json_encode($timetables);
```

Comment: Es que no tienes por qué introducir en un array lo que ya puedes obtener como un array. Cuando haces la consulta a través de PDO o MySQLi le puedes pedir que te devuelva los resultados en un array. En el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) puedes consultar los diferentes método fetch que ofrece PDO

Comment: Pero recuerda que debo dividir el campo date en tres (Day, month, Year)

Comment: Eso no es ningún problema, PHP tiene mil y una manera de darle formato a un fecha, o de obtener cualquier porción de una fecha por separado. No puedes condicionar tus resultados a un formato porque eso es lo de menos. Los datos se suelen formatear al momento de presentarlos. [Aquí puedes consultar las diferentes formas en que se puede presentar una fecha en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Comment: Hice la impresión directa sin guardar en una arreglo (En el foreach) peroigualmente lo muestra doble.

Comment: ¿Qué arreglo imprimiste? Quizá el SELECT te está duplicado datos a causa de algún JOIN? O quizá imprimes dentro de un bucle o código que se repite dos veces o imprimes en dos partes distintas. ?

Comment: Ésta es my consulta:

$stmt = Connex::conect()->prepare("SELECT name, image, date, start_time, end_time, color, description FROM $tabla WHERE court = $id");
  
  $stmt -> execute();

  return $stmt -> fetchAll();

  $stmt -> close();

Comment: Je je si es como imagino que llamas a tu consulta desde otra parte, veo un pequeño fallo, pues lo último debe ser el `return`: por eso aquí: `return $stmt -> fetchAll(); $stmt -> close();` el `$stmt` no se cerrará. Lo digo para que optimices el código. Siempre el `return` es lo último. Por otra parte, no se recomienda usar `fetchAll()` sobre todo si se esperan muchos resultados. Mejor usar `return $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` puedes hacer un `print_r($variable)` sobre la variable que recibe los valores de la consulta, ahí verás si realmente los datos están duplicados.

Answer (score 1):

Iremos por parte.

#### 1. Seguridad

Primero, la **seguridad**. En tu comentario presentas una consulta vulnerable a [inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php). Para evitar esto, es necesario usar sentencias preparadas y tener bien configurado PDO. Para configurar un PDO que no admita **falsas consultas preparadas** [puedes leer esto cuando tengas tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967), es un poco largo.

Daremos seguridad a la consulta de este modo:

```
$sql="SELECT name, image, date, start_time, end_time, color, description FROM $tabla WHERE court = :id";
$stmt = Connex::conect()->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id); 
$stmt->execute(); 
# Aquí sigue la lectura de datos mediante uno de los métodos explicados en (A) o en (B)
```

#### 2. Obtener los datos

A partir del `execute`, puedes optar por una de las formas siguientes para obtener los resultados:

- **(A)** Mediante el método `fetch`

  En este caso hay que abrir un bucle (generalmente `while`)  e ir metiendo cada fila dentro de un array. Dado que quieres un JSON, puedes usar el *fetch_style*  llamado `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, que devuelve los resultados en forma de array asociativo. De ese modo, al convertir a JSON tendrás tus pares clave/valor sin necesidad de obtenerlos manualmente cada vez. Sería tan simple como esto:

  ```
  $timetables = array();
  while ( $item= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $timetables[]=$item;
  } 
  $stmt -> close();
  return json_encode($timetables); //o echo, según el caso
  ```
- **(B)** Mediante el método `fetchAll`

  ¡Atención! `fetchAll` es más simple en el sentido de que no necesitas abrir un bucle e ir metiendo los datos. Te vuelca todos los resultados de una vez en una variable. Pero este método se recomienda solamente en aquellos casos en que la consulta no trae demasiadas filas ya que podrías tener problemas de memoria o de uso de recursos y el programa podría verse bloqueado.

  En cambio, si esperas pocas filas, el uso de este método puede ser idóneo. Este método, al igual que `fetch`, puede recibir en parámetro un *fetch_style*. Nótese que aquí no tienes que declarar `$timetables` como array previamente, al usarlo con `fetchAll` la variable tendrá como resultado un array asociativo con **todas las filas**:

  ```
  $timetables = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt -> close();
  return json_encode($timetables); //o echo, según el caso
  ```

#### 3. Conclusión

No necesitas nada más para obtener tus resultados. Si salen duplicados, deberás revisar si no estás imprimiendo dos veces, si no es un problema de la consulta, etc. En condiciones normales, un resultado hipotético, tanto si usas `fetch` como si usas `fetchAll`, sería el mismo.

**Resultado**

```
- fetch:

[{"name":"name1","image":"image1"},{"name":"name2","image":"image2"}]

- fetchAll:

[{"name":"name1","image":"image1"},{"name":"name2","image":"image2"}]
```

Comment: Gracias por responder nuevamente, yo lo había intentado con: fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); pero me da el siguiente error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\booking\backend\controllers\idController.php on line 14 (El mismo con cada campo), he verificado lo que devuelve la consulta con "var_dump", y me trae duplicado los campos de la BD, con "print_r" no

Comment: @Joe El warning indica que en la variable no hay nada llamado `name`. Creo que para resolver definitivamente el problema será mejor que edites la pregunta poniendo todo el código de la consulta a la bd y todo el código en el que llamas y muestras los datos.